# How to get images from email body with JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to get the value of cid: from the images contained in the body of the email at the time of reading to be able to replace the value of cid: by the base64 of the image, but I can not get this value, does anyone have any tips?

```
            try {
       MimeMultipart multipart = (MimeMultipart) msg.getDataHandler().getContent();
       int temp = 0, temp2 = 0;
       for (int k = 0; k < multipart.getCount(); k++) {
          MimeBodyPart bodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(k);
          String splited[] = new String[15];
          splited = bodyPart.getContentType().split(" ");

          if (!splited[0].equals("text/plain;") && !splited[0].equals("text/html;")) {
             MimeBodyPart part = bodyPart;
             MimeMultipart p = (MimeMultipart) part.getDataHandler().getContent();
             int count = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < p.getCount(); i++) {
                String mimeSplited[] = new String[15];
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Base64 decoder64 = new Base64();
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(eMail.getCorpoEmail());

                System.out.println("CID NAME" + i + " :" + p.getBodyPart(i).getFileName());
                System.out.println("CID TYPE" + i + " :" + p.getBodyPart(i).getContentType());

                if (i != p.getCount() - 1) {
                   p.getBodyPart(i + 1).getDataHandler().writeTo(bos);
                   mimeSplited = p.getBodyPart(i + 1).getContentType().split(" ");
                   s.insert(s.indexOf(":part" + (i + 1)) - 3, "data:" + mimeSplited[0] + " base64," + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()));
                } else {
                   p.getBodyPart(i).getDataHandler().writeTo(bos);
                   mimeSplited = p.getBodyPart(i).getContentType().split(" ");
                   s.insert(s.indexOf(":part" + i) - 3, "data:" + mimeSplited[0] + " base64," + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()));

                }
                eMail.setCorpoEmail(s.toString());
             }
          } else {
          }
```

This is my code until now.

**My new code:**

```
            try {
           MimeMultipart multipart = (MimeMultipart) msg.getDataHandler().getContent();
           int temp = 0, temp2 = 0;
           System.out.println("EMAIL BODY ->\n"+eMail.getCorpoEmail());
           for (int k = 0; k < multipart.getCount(); k++) {
              MimeBodyPart bodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(k);
              String splited[] = new String[15];
              splited = bodyPart.getContentType().split(" ");

              ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              String mimeSplited[] = new String[15];
              Base64 decoder64 = new Base64();
              StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(eMail.getCorpoEmail());
              String editedBody = "";
              int tempPosition = 0;
              if (bodyPart.getContentType().contains("image/")) {
                 MimeBodyPart part = bodyPart;
                 MimeMultipart p = (MimeMultipart) part.getDataHandler().getContent();

                 //THAT FUNCTION RETURNS NULL EVERY TIME
                 System.out.println("ID -> "+part.getContentID());

                 for (int i = 0; i < p.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (i != p.getCount() - 1) {
                       p.getBodyPart(i + 1).getDataHandler().writeTo(bos);
                       mimeSplited = p.getBodyPart(i + 1).getContentType().split(" ");

                       if (mimeSplited[0].equals("text/html;") || mimeSplited[0].equals("text/plain;")) {
                          s.insert(s.indexOf("src=") + 5, "data:" + "image/png;" + " base64," + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()));

                       } else {
                          s.insert(s.indexOf("src=") + 5, "data:" + mimeSplited[0] + " base64," + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()));

                       }
                       tempPosition = (s.indexOf("src=") + 5) + 23 + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()).length();
                       editedBody = editedBody.concat(s.substring(0, tempPosition));
                       s.delete(0, tempPosition);

                    } else {
                       p.getBodyPart(i).getDataHandler().writeTo(bos);
                       mimeSplited = p.getBodyPart(i).getContentType().split(" ");
//                       s.insert(s.indexOf("src=") + 5, "data:" + mimeSplited[0] + " base64," + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()));
                       tempPosition = (s.indexOf("src=") + 5) + 23 + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()).length();
                       editedBody = editedBody.concat(s.toString());
                    }
                    eMail.setCorpoEmail(editedBody);
                    bos.reset();
                 }
              } else {
              }
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("error: " + e);
        }
```

Email body

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
   xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
   <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)">
   <!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   </style><![endif]-->
   <style>
      <!--
      /* Font Definitions */

      @font-face {
         font-family: Calibri;
         panose-1: 2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
      }

      @font-face {
         font-family: Tahoma;
         panose-1: 2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;
      }

      /* Style Definitions */

      p.MsoNormal,
      li.MsoNormal,
      div.MsoNormal {
         margin: 0cm;
         margin-bottom: .0001pt;
         font-size: 11.0pt;
         font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
         mso-fareast-language: EN-US;
      }

      a:link,
      span.MsoHyperlink {
         mso-style-priority: 99;
         color: blue;
         text-decoration: underline;
      }

      a:visited,
      span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
         mso-style-priority: 99;
         color: purple;
         text-decoration: underline;
      }

      p.MsoAcetate,
      li.MsoAcetate,
      div.MsoAcetate {
         mso-style-priority: 99;
         mso-style-link: "Texto de balão Char";
         margin: 0cm;
         margin-bottom: .0001pt;
         font-size: 8.0pt;
         font-family: "Tahoma", "sans-serif";
         mso-fareast-language: EN-US;
      }

      span.EstiloDeEmail17 {
         mso-style-type: personal-compose;
         font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
         color: windowtext;
      }

      span.TextodebaloChar {
         mso-style-name: "Texto de balão Char";
         mso-style-priority: 99;
         mso-style-link: "Texto de balão";
         font-family: "Tahoma", "sans-serif";
      }

      .MsoChpDefault {
         mso-style-type: export-only;
         font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
         mso-fareast-language: EN-US;
      }

      @page WordSection1 {
         size: 612.0pt 792.0pt;
         margin: 70.85pt 3.0cm 70.85pt 3.0cm;
      }

      div.WordSection1 {
         page: WordSection1;
      }

      -->
   </style>
   <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
   <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
   </xml><![endif]-->
   <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
   <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
   <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
   </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body lang=PT-BR link=blue vlink=purple>
   <div class=WordSection1>
      <p class=MsoNormal>Teste
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>Teste
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>Teste
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>
         <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>
         <span style='mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
            <img width=1678 height=1009 id="Imagem_x0020_2" src="cid:image001.png@01D3BA15.6E238EE0">
         </span>
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>
         <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>Teste
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>Teste
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>Teste
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>
         <span style='mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
            <img width=1679 height=595 id="Imagem_x0020_3" src="cid:image002.png@01D3BA15.6E238EE0">
         </span>
         <o:p></o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>
         <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>
         <span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>Atenciosamente,
            <o:p></o:p>
         </span>
      </p>
      <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0>
         <tr>
            <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt'>
               <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:15.0pt'>
                  <span style='font-size:8.5pt;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
                     <img width=35 height=115 id="Imagem_x0020_1" src="cid:image003.jpg@01D3BA15.6E238EE0" alt="Descrição: http://www.kmm.com.br/_imagens/logo_assinatura.jpg">
                     <o:p></o:p>
                  </span>
               </p>
            </td>
            <td style='padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt 15.0pt'>
               <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:15.0pt'>
                  <b>
                     <span lang=EN-US style='font-size:8.5pt;color:#990000;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>Jeferson Luis Indejejczak</span>
                  </b>
                  <span lang=EN-US style='font-size:8.5pt;color:#333333;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
                     <br>
                  </span>
                  <b>
                     <span lang=EN-US style='font-size:8.5pt;color:black;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>Teste</span>
                  </b>
                  <span lang=EN-US style='font-size:8.5pt;color:#333333;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
                     <br>
                  </span>
                  <span style='font-size:8.5pt;color:#333333;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
                     <a href="mailto:jeferson.indejejczak@kmm.com.br">
                        <span lang=EN-US style='color:blue'>jeferson.indejejczak@kmm.com.br</span>
                     </a>
                  </span>
                  <span style='font-size:8.5pt;color:#333333;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
                     <span lang=EN-US>
                        <o:p></o:p>
                     </span>
                  </span>
               </p>
               <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto'>
                  <b>
                     <span style='font-size:8.5pt;color:#333333;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>KMM Engenharia de Sistemas</span>
                  </b>
                  <span style='font-size:8.5pt;color:#333333;mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
                     <br>Rua Padre Anacleto, 396 &#8211; Nova Rússia
                     <br>CEP 84.070-320 &#8211; Ponta Grossa &#8211; PR
                     <br>Tel: (42) 3026-3000
                     <br>
                     <a href="http://www.kmm.com.br/">
                        <span style='color:blue'>www.kmm.com.br</span>
                     </a>
                     <o:p></o:p>
                  </span>
               </p>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p class=MsoNormal>
         <span style='mso-fareast-language:PT-BR'>
            <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
         </span>
      </p>
      <p class=MsoNormal>
         <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
      </p>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
```

Comment: A good first step would be tu dump the message with msg.writeTo(System.out) or somplace else and then have a look at the different MIME entities. Once you know what's what you can then reconstruct your embedded images to data streams

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [ContentType](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/ContentType.html) class to parse the ContentType, instead of using String.split.

The Content-ID header of each image body part is accessible via the [MimeBodyPart.getContentID](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#getContentID--) method.

Comment: I've tried the getContentID but it returns null every single time, i don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you post the raw MIME content of a sample message that has this problem?  If the message includes html content with cid: references and the images have no Content-ID headers, that's not going to display properly in any mailer because there would be no way to associate the references with the images.

Comment: Still need to see the raw MIME content of the entire message.  If you don't know how to view that with your mailer, you can get it with JavaMail by doing `message.writeTo(new FileOuputStream("msg.txt"));`